# Use php variables into Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i am using http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/ to display images in my page, i need a way to pass variables from php to Jquery 
swipebox code that i am modifying is

```
plugin = this,
    elements = [], // slides array [{href:'...', title:'...'}, ...],
    elem = elem,
    selector = elem.selector,
    $selector = $(selector),
    isTouch = document.createTouch !== undefined || ('ontouchstart' in window) || ('onmsgesturechange' in window) || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints,
    supportSVG = !!(window.SVGSVGElement),
    winWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width(),
    winHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height(),
    html = '<div id="swipebox-overlay">\
            <div id="swipebox-slider"></div>\
            <div id="swipebox-caption"><a id="swipebox-close"></a></div>\
            <a id="swipebox-prev"></a>\
            <a id="swipebox-next"></a>\
            <div id="swipebox-action"><span class="swipebox-caption-text"></span>\
            <div class="listing-details-toolbar-inner">\
            <ul class="action-link-group float-l">\
            <li class="action-link-item">\
            <a href="#" id="shareListingBtn"\
                                        data-artid="<?php print $artId; ?>"\
                                        class="link-btn icon-btn ui-button-small"><span class="ic-icon share-icon"></span>Share</a>\
            </li>\
            <li class="action-link-item">\
            <a id="addToCollection"\
               data-artid="<?php print $artId;?>"\
               data-show_collections="<?php print TRUE; ?>"\
               data-title="<?php print $listing_single->title;?>"\
               data-description="<?php print $listing_single->description; ?>"\
               class="addto-Collection-btn link-btn ui-button-xsmall ui-button-primary">Collect it\
            </a>\
        </li>\
           <li class="action-link-item">\
           <?php print $smallLikeButton; ?>\
         </li>\
        </ul>\
        </div>\
    </div>';
```

As you can see html is different from original

```
html = '<div id="swipebox-overlay">\
            <div id="swipebox-slider"></div>\
            <div id="swipebox-caption"><a id="swipebox-close"></a></div>\
            <a id="swipebox-prev"></a>\
            <a id="swipebox-next"></a>\
            <div id="swipebox-action"><span class="swipebox-caption-text"></span></div>\
    </div>';
```

My problem is that i am adding buttons to plugin html and i need use variables like this one

```
<?php print $artId; ?>
```

[image]
what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your JavaScript file is not processed by PHP interpreter.

There are different solutions for your problem. For example, you can render

```
<script>
    var artId = <?php echo $artId; ?>; // assuming $artId is number
</script>
```

in your PHP rendering code and then use `artId` variable in JS-script.